# Select word with regex when previous words are specific (and sometimes variable)

Tags: regex

I am trying to highlight (or find) any word that is preceded by another word, being `define`, and another specific word to be highlighted (`as`), when `define` is present, etc. Basically, I need to find words that are found because of other regex searches, but only targetting each word independently.

For example, having the following string:

`define MyFile as File`

In that case, `define` is searched using the regex statement `\b-?define\b`. I also need to find `MyFile` *if* it is preceded directly by `define`. Plus, `as` needs to be found as well *only if* it is preceded directly by a word, in this case `MyFile`, which is preceded by `define`, and this goes on and on.

How can this be done? I have messed around quite a bit to find how to highlight `MyFile` correctly, without any success. As for the specific recursive search of `as` and `File`, I am clueless.

Keep in mind that all the regex expressions must be **separate**, since I will use this as a Sublime Text custom syntax highlight match finder.

Comment: Hint: use `-?\bdefine\b` rather than `\b-?define\b`

Comment: It looks like you need lookaheads here, e.g. `(?<=\bdefine)(\s+\w+)` will match `MyFile` (together with preceding whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
define\s([\w]+)\sas\s([\w]+)$
```

This regex code would capture all words after define separated by a space and all words after as separated by space as well
check this regex : https://regex101.com/r/aQ0yO0/2

Comment: `[\w\d]+` doesn't make much sense, because `\w` already includes digits. You want just `\w+` .

Answer (score 0):

For not having context of what the data looks like...this is a naive way of doing it but it's pretty intuitive. However, it doesn't use regex.  The other examples are good ways to use regex.

```
seq = "word1 defined as blah blahh blahhh word2 defined as hello helloo"

words_of_interest = []

list_of_words = seq.split(" ")
for i,word in enumerate(list_of_words):
    if word == "defined":
        words_of_interest.append(list_of_words[i-1])
print words_of_interest
#['word1', 'word2']
```

Answer (score -1):

The regular expression is always going to encompass the "define" as well. The trick is to use capture groups and refer to them afterwards. The specific way how to do this depends on the "flavor" of your regex.

As I'm not familiar with Sublime's regex, I'm just going to present an example in sed:

```
$ sed -e 's/define \([A-Za-z]*\)/include \1/g' <<< "define MyFile as File"
include MyFile as File
```

This example replaces all "define"s with "include"s - and adds whatever was captured by what's inside the group (the regex `[A-Za-z]*` in this case). Not too useful, but hopefully explanatory :)

The capture group is denoted by the escaped brackets, and (in sed) referenced by the escaped number (representing the index) of the group.

---

I believe it's capture groups as a concept that you're looking for, rather than any specific regex.